# Access Object in Array in React Using Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, immutable.js

I'm trying to access an objects in array from JSON, right now I'm using React and Immutable w/ Typescript and i'm able to access the object using

`const MentorContracts = MentorInfo && (MentorInfo.get("contractsAwardedToSdbTotals") as Map<{}, {}>);`

however in my JSX, i'm unable to access the data like this

`<Typography>FY:{MentorContracts.get("fiscalYear")}</Typography>`

**How would I access contractsAwardstoSdbTotals.fiscalYear?**

here is the JSON data

```
"mentor": {
    "address": {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string",
      "zip": "string"
    },
    "cageCode": "string",
    "contractsAwardedToSdbTotals": [
      {
        "amount": 0,
        "contractType": "DOD_SUB",
        "fiscalYear": 0,
        "percentage": 0
      }
    ],
```

Comment: you need to map and render. since MentorContracts is a List

Comment: can you show me an example? i'm new to using immutable and react @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: also my <typography> element is already in my render function. i'm not sure how to use the map function @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `MentorContracts` is a List, you need to map over it and render the desired result

```
render() {
   const MentorContracts = MentorInfo && MentorInfo.get("contractsAwardedToSdbTotals");
   return (
       <div>
          {MentorContracts.map((elem) => (
               <Typography>FY: {elem.get("fiscalYear")}</Typography>
           ))}
       </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: one more point... I'm writing this in Typescript so elem was be undefined. How would I fix this? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: also how would i get the array index of 0? would it be {elem.get("fiscalYear")[0]}? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: if you map(loop), you will get each element in the iteration, However if you just want the first element, you can simply write `<Typography>FY: {MentorContracts.getIn([0, "fiscalYear"])}</Typography>`

Comment: Glad to have helped